# Test if powershell remoting is enabled

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have been looking and can't find specifically what I am looking for, I need a way that I can test about 900 machines and tell whether or not powershell remoting is enabled, I figured out that with the script below I can verify that powershell is installed but it doesn't check that it can actually remotely manage the machine, any ideas?

```
function Check-PSVersion
{

[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $ComputerName
)
if (Test-Path $ComputerName)
{
    $Computers = Get-Content $ComputerName
}
Else
{
    $Computers = $ComputerName
}

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Try
    {
        Write-Host "Checking Computer $Computer"
        $path = "\\$Computer\C$\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
        if (test-path $path) { (ls $path).VersionInfo }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Powershell isn't installed" -ForegroundColor 'Red'
        }
        Write-Host "Finished Checking Computer $Computer"
    }

    catch { }
}
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the Test-WSMan cmdlet to check whether the WinRM service is running on a remote computer.

```powershell
[bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName 'ComputerName' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
```

Comment: If it doesn't return an error it is on and if it is disabled it returns an error, thanks

Comment: any idea how to make that come back as a Boolean so it is less text to sort through?

Comment: [bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName 'ComputerName' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

Comment: also, though Test-WSMan can return true, you may not have access, so [bool](invoke-command -ComputerName 'ComputerName' -ScriptBlock {"hello from $env:COMPUTERNAME"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

Answer (score 2):

at the risk of being off-topic ...

```
function server_available?( $_server_to_act_on ) {
   if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $_server_to_act_on -Count 1 -Quiet ) {
     Write-Host "`nTest-Connection: $_server_to_act_on OK" -NoNewline
     if ( [bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName $_server_to_act_on -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ) {
       Write-Host ", Test-WSMan: $_server_to_act_on OK" -NoNewline
       if ( [bool](Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_server_to_act_on -ScriptBlock {"hello from $env:COMPUTERNAME"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ) {
         Write-Host ", Invoke-Command: $_server_to_act_on OK" -NoNewline
         return $true
       }
     }
  }
  return $false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working from Straffs code above, this is my working version of how to determine if PS Remoting is working on 1 or more machines. Save the code and put it in the same folder with a file named "PCList.txt" Run the script and it will display the status as each system in the list AND produce a new report each time you run it in .CSV format directly clickable into excel.  Put one machine per line  in the PCList.txt file. You must have local admin access to the remote machines for this to work, always "Run As Administrator"

```
function Test-CanRemoteSystetmRunPSCmd( $_server_to_act_on ) 
{

  Write-host "`n`n$Counter of $Total - Testing System:`t$_server_to_act_on`n"
  if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $_server_to_act_on -Count 1 -Quiet ) 
  {
    Write-Host "`nTest-Connection: $_server_to_act_on OK, " -NoNewline
    if ( [bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName $_server_to_act_on -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ) 
    {
      Write-Host "Test-WSMan: $_server_to_act_on OK, " -NoNewline
      if ( [bool](Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_server_to_act_on -ScriptBlock {"hello from $env:COMPUTERNAME"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ) 
      {
        Write-Host "Invoke-Command: $_server_to_act_on OK. `n"  
        return "$_server_to_act_on,SUCCESS"
      }
      Else
      {

        Return "$_server_to_act_on,FAILED Invoke-Command"
        Continue 

      }
    }
    Else
    {

      Return "$_server_to_act_on,FAILED Test-WSMAN"
      Continue 

    }
  }
  Else
  {

    Return "$_server_to_act_on,FAILED Test-Connection"
    Continue 

  }  
}

Clear-Host
# Intialze the report name  and header anchored in the current script folder 
$_NewRunTime    = Get-Date                                                              # Initialize the time of the script being run
$_LastRunTime   = $_NewRunTime
$_Year          = $_NewRunTime.Year
$_Month         = $_NewRunTime.Month
$_Day           = $_NewRunTime.Day
$_Hour          = $_NewRunTime.Hour
$_Min           = $_NewRunTime.Minute
$_Sec           = $_NewRunTime.Second
$_Report_DateTime_Header = "$_Year.$_Month.$_Day.$_Hour.$_Min.$_Sec"
$_report_File = "$PSScriptRoot" + '\' + "$_Report_DateTime_Header"  + '_PSRemotingStatusReport.csv'
$_ReportHeader = "Computer Name,PS Remoting Status,Test Time"
 Out-File -FilePath $_report_File -InputObject $_ReportHeader -Encoding UTF8  # Add a line to the report

$PCList = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\PCList.txt"
$Total = $PCList.Count
$Counter = 0

ForEach ($PC in $PCList)
{
  $Counter = $Counter + 1
 $T = Measure-Command {$RemoteCommandCheck = Test-CanRemoteSystetmRunPSCmd $PC}

 $TestTimeTotal = $T.Totalseconds
  If($RemoteCommandCheck -like "*Fail*")
  {

    Write-Host "$RemoteCommandCheck,$TestTimeTotal" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow

  }
  Else
  {

    Write-Host "$RemoteCommandCheck,$TestTimeTotal" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

  }
  $RemoteCommandCheck + ',' + $TestTimeTotal | Out-File -FilePath $_report_File -Encoding UTF8 -Append
}
```